# Trying to implement elem with a foldl any

Tags: haskell

I am new in haskell, i am trying right now to implement "elem" with a "foldl any" in Haskell, but it won't work.

My any :

`any' p = foldl' (\y x -> p x || y) False`

and this is my elem :

`elem' y = foldl' (\z x -> x==y || z) False`

my first try was this :

`elemfa p y = not (any' (\x -> not (p x)) y)`

but i am getting an error everytime

Comment: Your `elemfa` uses a predicate `p`, so it does not check for an element, it checks if all elements satisfy a given predicate.

Comment: Here it is probably also better to use a `foldr`, since then from the moment you find an element, you can stop searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `elemfa :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool` makes use of `any''''`, but that function does not exists. If you rewrite this to:

```
elemfa :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
elemfa p y = not (any' (\x -> not (p x)) y)
```

You can make it more clean with:

```
elemfa :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
elemfa p = not . any' (not . p)
```

It will at least produce output. This function will check if *all* elements satisfy the given predicate.

That being said, it is not ideal to use a `foldl` here for `any`, `elem` and `elemfa`, since that means it will keep iterating over the list, even if it found an element that satisfies the predicate. If you thus work on an infinite list, it will not return `True`, even if it found an element:

```
Prelude Data.List> elem' 1 (1 : repeat 2)
… keeps looking …
```

Here [**`foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) can be used to stop searching once the element has been found, for example:

```
any' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
any' p = foldr (\x -> (p x ||)) False

elem' :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => a -> f a -> Bool
elem' x = any' (x==)

all' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
all' p = not . any (not . p)
```

Comment: @Maxo: well without it, I do not get any errors, unless of course the types in your function call do not match. How did you test it?

Comment: i test it with " elemfa 1 [1,2,3,4,5] " in ghci. And i am getting this error : <interactive>:3:8: error:
    * No instance for (Num (Integer -> Bool))
        arising from the literal `1'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the first argument of `elemfa', namely `1'
      In the expression: elemfa 1 [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]
      In an equation for `it': it = elemfa 1 [1, 2, 3, ....]

Comment: @Maxo: but as said in the answer, your `elemfa` finds out if a *predicate* holds for all elements. So `elemfa odd [1,3,5,7]` will return `True`, since for all elements it hold. The first parameter is thus *not* an *element*, but a *predicate*.